# Deleting a file with filename "~"

Tags: linux, filesystems

While saving file in gvim with :w, I think I accidently typed :w~, it saved the filename as ~.
I did not think much of it and tried to delete it in terminal, like below

rm ~

This turned disastrous as it got interpreted as my home directory ~/. It deleted files from my home directory.

My question is why linux allowed ~ as filename and how to delete that from terminal. Any command will be treated like home directory for that.

Comment: Not a programming question, voted to close. This belongs to [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix filesystems support a wide range of characters, including symbolic links. **To specifically target a file with special characters (like unicode arabic, chinese text, or emojis) you need to use quotes**.

In your case, to remove a file named `~`

```sh
rm "~"
```

or

```sh
rm "/path/to/file/in/quotes/~"
```

**Note:** *Here we use quotes because we need to tell the shell prompt that its a file, not `~/` the user $HOME directory.*

**I hope that helped :)**